# GIt - Can't clone on wifi network alone

Tags: 14.04, wireless, git, clone

I have a wifi router at my home.When i connected my laptop to Wifi and try to clone i'm getting this error:

```
git clone https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Dialer.git
Cloning into 'android_packages_apps_Dialer'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Dialer.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Network is unreachable
```

But Internet is working fine through Browser and Terminal (apt-get).

Same Wifi connected on my mobile and connected to laptop using USB tethering. Now git clone is working fine.I dont know why same wifi not working when connected directly on laptop.

Comment: Connect to again and run `ping google.com` .  Does it connect

Comment: Yes,i think except git clone everthing working fine through WIFI.

Comment: Maybe github is having a problem?

Comment: I dont think so. Because github working fine when connected through USB tethering on same wifi router.

Comment: When you say `i think` don't understand please be explicit

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure ping working fine even working for github.com

Comment: Restart everything and try again, if UT works on connected USB then it should on WiFi. Please restart everything

Comment: After restarting it worked. But sometimes its happens in between and I have to restart again to make it work.

Comment: This happens to me on my house wifi. Not sure why `git` command doesn't work for both github and bitbucket. I see this error `ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Operation timed out`. Could be a problem with DNS provider!